# Green's identity with a different norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integration, norms, hausdorff-measure

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain with a smooth boundary $\Gamma$. Suppose that $f, g \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are of class $C^\infty( \overline{\Omega})$. Then Green's first identity states that
$$ \int_\Omega \nabla f \cdot \nabla g d\Omega = \int_\Gamma f \nabla g \cdot \hat{n} d\Gamma - \int_\Omega f \nabla^2 g d\Omega.$$

The above integrals over $\Omega$ could be interpreted as integrated with respect to the Hausdorff measure induced by the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Integral over $\Gamma$ could also be interpreted as an integral with respect to measure induced by the same norm.

Suppose that instead of using the euclidean norm one were to choose some other norm $\| \cdot \|$. Since in a finite-dimensional normed space all norms are equivalent, the terms $\nabla f$, $\nabla g$, and $\nabla^2 g$ wouldn't change regardless of the used norm. However, changing the norm most likely would change the mentioned Hausdorff measure and the measure on the boundary, thus affecting all the integrals.

> **Question.** Is there a similar result to Green's identity, but with the mentioned change of norm applied?

I'm especially interested in whether such change would also require one to change the meaning of the term $\cdot \hat{n}$, i.e. one would need to redefine what "normal" to the boundary means in that case.